# KDE plasma input method settings shows "Cannot connect to Fcitx by DBus, is Fcitx running?"

Tags: 20.04, plasma-5, fcitx

When I open Input Method settings in KDE plasma and it showed "Cannot connect to Fcitx by DBus, is Fcitx running?" and I can't do any changes to input method since everything is grayed out.

Only "Input Method" tab affected. "Global Config" and "Addon Config" works fine:

[image: "Screenshot 1"]

I also have Gnome installed and this happened after changing some system-wide language settings (Setting system-wide language to English, previously Traditional Chinese). Everything worked normally before the change.

When I tried `dbus-launch fcitx`, it shows `Start XIM error. Another XIM deamon named ibus is running?`

I can provide more information if needed. Thank you.

Some system information:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Kernel: 5.13.0-37-generic
DE installed: Ubuntu-desktop(Gnome 3.36.8), KDE Plasma 5.18.8
Windowing system: Wayland
```

Language support settings in Gnome:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Region & Language settings in Gnome settings:

[image: Screenshot 3]